# Set a Jquery dialog title bar style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want that some of my jquery dialogs, not all, have a different title bar color.
How can I acheive this?
I used the property dialogClass:"myClass" in desired dialogs but this doesen't change the title bar, just the dialog body.

Thank you!!

Comment: You're going to have to give us more than that Toni! A link to a fiddle or your page URL would be best.

Comment: I'm triying that but I'm not able to run the code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifying a `dialogClass` adds this class to the outermost `div` wrapping the entire dialog including the title bar, so you just have to make sure that you CSS rule is targeting the correct element. For instance:

```
.myDialogClass .ui-widget-header {
  background: purple;
}
```

Comment: Nearly!! It changed the dialog title bar background but the text background is not changed.

Comment: Try the ".ui-dialog-title" class.

    .myDialogClass .ui-widget-header .ui-dialog-title {
  background: purple;
}

Comment: I had to use both the Gustav and Billy answers. The first to change the title bar color, the second to change the text color.

Comment: For me, Gustav's worked by itself. I think it only works by itself if you don't have a style for the title at all. If you define something else for the title, then I think it's own default background will override the widget-header.

Answer (score 5):

```
div.ui-widget-header {
  border: 1px solid #3b678e;
  background: #3b678e url("images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_3b678e_500x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: if you'd elaborate on this it would make this a better answer

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
   div#myDialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
      background-color: red;
   }
```

The `.ui-dialog-titlebar` is what you are looking to apply your style to.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. The content element becomes a _sibling_ of the title bar.