# Make jQuery UI modal dialog draggable after removing titlebar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I had to hide the titlebar of a jQuery UI modal dialog on my page because I didn't like the look of it and wanted my own custom title area. Is it possible to make the dialog draggable even after removing the titlebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have your custom styling for the title, you may just want to override the styles of the dialog title area.

Have a look at this question. Or you can have a look with FireBug to see what styles are applied and override them in your own css.

[Set a Jquery dialog title bar style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453466/set-a-jquery-dialog-title-bar-style)

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I should've done in the first place!

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that. But you have to add extra bit of html and javascript.

I have created a fiddle for you. This will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ctL8/1/

```
$('#dragable').draggable();
$('#dragable').hide();
$('#Btn').click(function(){
$('#dragable').show();
})
$('#close').click(function(){
$('#dragable').hide();
})
```

Hope this helps you

The trick is in draggable. this makes any content draggable.

Comment: Thanks! While this is a helpful answer, I think I needed the other answer just posted by Littlefool :)